# How to change get_result() in my project so it would still work with the JSON later on?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have this code from tutorial, where I pass User details from PHP to Android via Json. But my DB doesn't support get_result().

This is what I do with the results:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // user is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["surname"] = $user["surname"];
        $response["user"]["address"] = $user["address"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

This is how I'm supposed to send them:

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

            $stmt->close();

            // verifying user password
            $salt = $user['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $user['password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $user;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

But the line `$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();` doesn't work in my database, so could anyone please tell me how I can change the code in the second file so it would still work in the first one? I've read php guides and so on, but I didn't manage to make anything out of that.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: My database doesn't support `get_result()` function, so I'm looking for an alternative way to get the same result

Comment: you need to add error checking in your php code and add it to your array in json data otherwise your app won't know if the connection failed or the password is wrong

Comment: I don't get any other errors, I just can't use the `get_result()` function and need an alternative for that in this project. Do you know it?

Comment: i use json_encode for Xcode but i check the errors first you should build a array with output including a error staus error is user not found or login is wrong where do you check if query is wrong ?